# Proof of $E[XY|\mathscr{H}]=XE[Y|\mathscr{H}]$ for $\mathscr{H}$-measurable $X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

I reckon this is a pretty trivial result in the context of elementary probability, but how would one show it in the context of measure-theoretic probability theory?
That is, that $E[XY|\mathscr{H}]=XE[Y|\mathscr{H}]$ for $\mathscr{H}$-measurable $X$ where $X$ and $Y$ are random variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $X=I_A$ for some measurable set $A$ (w.r.t. $\mathcal H$) this follows from definition of conditional expectation. Now go to simple functions and then take limits. This gives the result for $X$ non-negative. Now write $X$ as $X^{+}-X^{-}$. You have to assume that $E|XY| <\infty$ for the result to be true.

Comment: I see, it should follow in that first step from, for $S \in \mathscr{H}$, $E[\mathbb{I}_{S}(\mathbb{I}_{A}E[Y|\mathscr{H}])]=E[\mathbb{I}_{S \cap A}E[Y|\mathscr{H}]]=E[\mathbb{I}_{S \cap A}Y]$ and uniqueness.

Comment: *That is, because the last term in that expression is equivalent to $E[\mathbb{I}_{S} \mathbb{I}_{A} Y] = E[E[\mathbb{I}_{A} Y | \mathscr{H}] \mathbb{I}_{S}]$ and then by uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
Z=E[XY\mid \mathscr{H}]-XE[Y\mid \mathscr{H}]=E[XY\mid \mathscr{H}]-XY+X[Y-E[Y\mid \mathscr{H}]]
$$
and note that $Z$ is a $\mathscr{H}$ measurable function. Further for $H\in \mathscr{H}$, we have that
$$
EZI_H=E(E[XY\mid \mathscr{H}]-XY)I_H+E(Y-E[Y\mid \mathscr{H}])XI_H=0
$$
by the definition of conditional expectation where we use the fact that $XI_{H}$ is $\mathscr{H}$ measurable. Taking $H=I(Z>0)$ and $H=I(Z<0)$ it follows that 
$$
Z=0
$$
with probability one from which the claim follows.